# Connect 2 networks 2 km apart and share each Internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I want to connect 2 networks together. They each have a cable internet service and are each on a different subnet (192.168.0.1/24 and 192.168.1.1/24). I intend to physically connect the 2 with a line of sight wireless link. I want to know what other equipment or software is required to make the connection work so that computers on one network can use either Internet connection, sort of like a backup or failover. The computers on each network do not need to talk to each other but it doesn't matter if they can. This arrangement is primarily for Internet backup.

Comment: You could just set up a VPN - see https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=132865#:~:text=two%20(2)%20routers-,Setting%20up%20a%20VPN%20Tunnel%20on%20two%20(2)%20routers,network%2C%20such%20as%20the%20Internet.

Comment: But what if you lose connection to the Internet at one end? Then only the other end would work. That's not a backup. You need 2 separate independent paths for a backup.

Comment: So you want either side to use either connection?  You want to use the other side's internet if the internet connection on one side goes, not a file backup.

Comment: Correct. I want to access either Internet connection from either network, preferrably transparently. If these internet connections were local I could use a load balance router but I want to devise a system where I could use the equivalent of a LBR but have the Internet connections physically separate.

Comment: Do you have control over the area in between the two sites?  If you don't then someone could build something in between that could block the signal.

Comment: No I don't but it's a residential area and it's very unlikely that someone will build a tall building the the line of sight I'm considering. I'm prepared to spend some money on the backup if it's at all feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You need routers capable of handling multiple networks and that can handle failover and tailback functionality as well as an AP and AP client. Over the distance contemplated you will likely need prosumer or professional WiFi gear,  as well as point to point antennas and good line-of-site visibility between the points. A 2kn shit - while definitely doable - is no trivial feat.

Loosely speaking you can treat your WiFi link like a long virtual  ethernet cable, so at a push you could use a couple of  decent consumer grade  routers running dd-wrt - although customising this to convert one of the LAN ports to be a second wan port is a more advanced skill, as is handling failover and failback.

There are other more advanced strategies involving dynamic routing as well, but again likely harder.

Comment: I intend to make the wireless link of 2 km using 2 Ubiquiti 5GHz airMAX AC LiteBeam Gen2 which are capable of up to 16 km. It would become like a virtual erthernet cable as you say. What I'm after is the specific way to configure this system to achieve the result I want - that is making each Internet connection visible to both networks.